# Request Payload HTTP (Создание запроса через Postman curl)

Tags: http

Здравствуйте, как мне правильно составить запрос Request Payload через Postman или CURL?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[{"action":"wow_Services","method":"cmdGetCharactersList","data":[{"page":1,"start":0,"limit":25,"sort":[{"property":"name","direction":"ASC"}]}],"type":"rpc","tid":3},{"action":"wow_Services","method":"cmdGetGeneralInfo","data":null,"type":"rpc","tid":4},{"action":"wow_Services","method":"cmdGetServersList","data":null,"type":"rpc","tid":5},{"action":"wow_Services","method":"cmdGetMessagesList","data":[{"page":1,"start":0,"limit":25,"sort":[{"property":"fdatetime","direction":"DESC"}]}],"type":"rpc","tid":6},{"action":"wow_Services","method":"cmdAccountFriendsList","data":[{"page":1,"start":0,"limit":25,"sort":[{"property":"online","direction":"DESC"}]}],"type":"rpc","tid":7}]
```

Comment: Замените картонку техтом.

Comment: готово. измениL

Comment: это у вас Google Chrome?

Comment: да Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываете вкладку **Network**. Выбираете нужный вам запрос и нажимаете правую клавишу мыши (или что-то, что откроет всплывающее меню). Выбираете **Copy** -> **Copy as cURL**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В буфере обмена будет нужная вам команда.

Вы можете её импортировать в **Postman** используя кнопку **Import**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: просто импортируйте полученную команду в Postman и он сам все правильно вставит.

Comment: я добавил это в ответ

Comment: скорей всего это user-agent. попробуйте из curl выполнить запрос.

Comment: это ожидаемый результат?